# Why do i get the error "error: conflicting types for 'felszab'" in the folowing code?

Tags: c

The function was written to free a list i created earlier...

```
rekord *felszab(rekord *el)
{
    rekord *temp;
    for(rekord *mozgo=eleje;mozgo=!NULL;mozgo=temp)
    {
        temp=mozgo->kov;
        free(mozgo);
    }
    return el;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call it without the prototype. Compiler assumes int as parameter and return value. Then it sees the definition having other types. Thus conflicting types